# Wildfly 10 HTTP/2 Server Push

Tags: jboss, wildfly, http2, wildfly-10

I've created Java EE web project and set up a Wildfly 10 Server. I have an `index.html` which includes some images. However this images run through a server push, which is really nice. 
My question is, where is this server push initiated from? My first thought was the `LearningPushHandler` from `io.undertow`, but I did not set up any handler. If so, how can I see, that this Handler is used and how can I disable or override it?